# remove 1SD values from a dataset in Python (outlier detection)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to remove all of the 1SD values:

```
         Name        Time1           Time2

         kim         700             650
         kim         2               20
         kim         1               1020
         danny       1000            50
         danny       3000            25
         danny       5               500
         danny       4000            1
```

Desired output:

```
       Name        Time1           Time2

         kim         700             650
                                     1020
         danny       1000            50
         danny       3000            25
                     500
         danny       4000
```

dput:

```
 structure(list(Name = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("danny", 
 "kim"), class = "factor"), Time1 = c(700L, 2L, 1L, 1000L, 3000L, 
 5L, 4000L), Time2 = c(650L, 20L, 1020L, 50L, 25L, 500L, 1L)), class = "data.frame",      row.names = c(NA, 
 -7L))
```

What I have tried:

```
  total= df.groupby(['Time1','Time2']).sum()


  total['total_time'] = df['Time1'] + df['Time2']



  m = df['total_time'].mean()
  err = 2 * df['total_time'].std()
```

But I am still trying to see how to actually remove the 1SD values from the dataset.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how do you obtain expected output? do you want do it by names?

Comment: Hi, yes. I have completed this within R, with the help of a stackoverflow member: tot<-df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  filter(abs(scale(Time1)) < 1)          -------I was curious to see how this can be completed in Python

Comment: Must it be inside mean + std and mean -std?